# Why ImageView has was wrong location when I use anchors programmatically?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, autolayout, uicollectionviewcell

everyone. I have problems with the collection view cell which I build programmatically using anchors.

Cell

```
private lazy var iconView: UIImageView =  {
    let image = UIImageView()
    image.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    image.clipsToBounds = true
    return image
}()
private lazy var label: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.numberOfLines = 2
    label.font = NeoSansPro.regular.of(size: 12)
    label.textAlignment = .center
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    label.sizeToFit()
    return label
}()
```

Config anchor

```
 override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        setupUI()
    }
    
    
    func setupUI() {
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate( [
            iconView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 32),
            iconView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 32),
            iconView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerXAnchor, constant: 0),
            iconView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerYAnchor, constant: -16),
            
            label.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: iconView.bottomAnchor, constant: 8),
            label.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor, constant: 4),
            label.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: 4),
            label.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor, constant: 4),
        ])
        
    }
```

as the result 1 and 9 cells has wrong[image] image location and label width biggest that cell width.

Comment: Problem is, `layoutSubviews` is called many times. So you are just piling up more and more constraints every time.

Comment: Activate your constraints in the same place you are adding the views (such as in `init`) - it looks like you think you need to wait for `layoutSubviews()`.

Comment: Ok so you are not even listening to what I said.

Comment: ooh, @matt sorry I understood

Comment: @matt I moved my setupUI into init() and now all images located at the left top corner

Comment: And now what does the View Debugger tell you about that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Add views first then add constraints it will work.**

[image]

```
private lazy var iconView: UIImageView =  {
    let image = UIImageView()
    image.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    image.image = UIImage(named: "1")
    return image
}()
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    backView.layer.cornerRadius = 5
    self.contentView.addSubview(iconView)
    setUpView()
}

func setUpView() {
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate( [
        iconView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40),
        iconView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40),
        iconView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.centerXAnchor, constant: 0),
        iconView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.centerYAnchor, constant: -16)
    ])
}
```